# Autofill cells when a checkbox is checked

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, checkbox, autofill

I would like to be able to add names to the empty numbered cells when the checkbox next to the name is checked.  When I uncheck a box, i would like the name removed and replaced with the next name that I check.  The order the names show in the cells does not matter.

I honestly have no idea how to do this or if it is possible.

[Spreadsheet image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ylr7c.png)

Comment: Please show what you have tried and add a brief description of your efforts to find helpful content from this site, include links to the most relevant posts,  explain why they didn't  help you and / or what was clear.

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter()`, like this:

`=filter(D4:D, E4:E)`

The formula assumes that the names are in column `D4:E` and the checkboxes in column `E4:E`.